# How to build the updated Uber Java SDK? Assistance with gradle build required

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, uber-api

I have been using maven for project management and have no idea on running gradle. This is the Uber Java sdk which uses Gradle for build purposes.
https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk

Until now I had been using the SDK by adding the following artifact to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.uber.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>rides</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The last version which was officially released was 0.2.0. Since then, support for getting ride receipts has been added which can be seen in the source code. I need to fetch ride receipts and hence require the latest changes.

It seems the build.gradle file has a line "apply plugin: 'maven'" which should add the project to my local maven repo. However, when I run
gradle install, I get the following error:

> Failed to notify task execution listener.
>
> > Changelog must be updated with v{0.2.1} before release. Please check /home/user/projects/rides-java-sdk-master/CHANGELOG.md

How do I rectify this error and get the latest build in my local maven repo?

After I changed the CHANGELOG.md file to begin with V0.2.1, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':install'.
>
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
>
> Cannot publish artifact 'rides-java-sdk-master.zip (com.uber.sdk:rides-java-sdk-master:0.2.1)'
> (/home/nikhar/projects/rides-java-sdk-master/build/distributions/rides-java-sdk-master-0.2.1.zip)
> as it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to fork the repo, build it, or install the pom locally to get the latest chnages. Just referencing the artifact from maven central (ie https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.uber.sdk/rides/0.2.0) should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. As I said, the feature that I require, this commit in particular:
https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/commit/b137b927fcaadeb0eb34122bbdf32d27dff05023
 was added after v0.2.0 was released. The getRideReceipt function is not available if I reference the latest artifact from maven central.

Comment: Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see the problem now. We have unreleased changes on master. We'll be launching v0.3.0 ASAP and you should be able to use that. I've filed an issue here: https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/issues/12

Comment: Thanks. Subscribed to the issue. :)

Comment: This should be fixed now. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks.
Though is version 0.3.0 not on maven central yet?
https://maven-repository.com/artifact/com.uber.sdk/rides

Comment: Not sure how long it takes to sync there, but it should be live now: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.uber.sdk%22%20AND%20a%3A%22rides%22